# Скрипт поиска по базе данных на AJAX

Tags: ajax, php, база-данных, mysql

Вот скрипт пиоска на AJAX без перезагузки страницы. Почему он в Опере работает нормально, а в остальных браузерах выдает ошибку при вводе некоторых символов.

> `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:  \home\localhost\www\getuser.php on line 12`
> `Не найдено`

Вот сам скрипт.

getuser.php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "zip", "123123") or die("Ошибка подключения к базе");
mysql_select_db("zip") or die("База не найдена");
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8;");
$user_get = $_GET['q'];
iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $user_get);
//echo $user_get;
if ((isset($user_get))) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `lastname` LIKE '%{$user_get}%'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            echo $row['lastname'] . "&nbsp;" . $row['name'] . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Не найдено";
    }

} else {
    echo "Ничего нет";
}
?>
```

ajax.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8;">
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Код для IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // Код для for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) // если передача данных закончена то..
        {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) // если ответ сервера 200 ок то
            {
                // вставляем в элемент ID="test"
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
            } else //если ответ сервера не 200 то
            {
                // выдам соообщение
                alert('Ошибка подключения сервера'); 
            }
        } else //если данные с сервера не загружены то
        {
            // вставляем в элемент ID="test"
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Загрузка...';
        }
    }
    // отправляем методом GET файлу getuser.php
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Начните вводить имя пользовотеля :</b></p>
<form>
<input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" size="20" />
</form>
<p><span id="test"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Какие символы вызывают ошибку?
2. Навскидку - преобразуйте параметры, передаваемые через URL таким образом:
   xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+**encodeURIComponent**(str),true);

Comment: Более подробно можно посмотреть здесь: [XMLHTTPRequest](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/).

Comment: Блин реально заработало. СПАСИБО!!! А так половину алфавита вызывало ошибку.Кстати еще вопросик: А как сделать что бы скрипт искал текст из двух разделов `name` и `lastname` (что бы поиск пользователя происходил по имени и фамилии, а не только по фамилии,как сдесь) ???

Comment: Используйте оператор AND для перечисления, пример : WHERE x='$x' AND z='$z'

Comment: По-моему, для ТС больше подойдет использование OR а не AND